# MAX Date Subquery SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to join a max date in a subquery but I get an error.  Im using SQL server

```
SELECT Headcount.[Snapshot Date]
, Headcount.[ID]
, Assessment.[Assessment Date]
, Assessment.[Code]

FROM Headcount INNER JOIN Assessment ON Assessment.[ID] = Headcount.[ID]
WHERE Assessment.[Assessment Date] = 
                 (SELECT MAX(CAST(Assessment.[Assessment Date] as datetime)) 
                  FROM Assessmnet AS Z 
                  WHERE Z.[ID] = Assessment.[ID] 
                       AND Assessment.[Assessment Date] <= Headcount.[Snapshot Date]
                 )
```

But I get an error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot about the alias `Z` that you specify in your subquery. If you use `Assessment` in your subquery, then he considers the `Assessment` from the outside query because `Assessment` has name `Z` in your subquery.

```
SELECT Headcount.[Snapshot Date]
, Headcount.[ID]
, Assessment.[Assessment Date]
, Assessment.[Code]

FROM Headcount INNER JOIN Assessment ON Assessment.[ID] = Headcount.[ID]
WHERE Assessment.[Assessment Date] = 
                 (SELECT MAX(CAST(Z.[Assessment Date] as datetime)) 
                  FROM Assessment AS Z 
                  WHERE Z.[ID] = Assessment.[ID] 
                       AND Z.[Assessment Date] <= Headcount.[Snapshot Date]
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is within the sub query on the `where` condition, try something like this:

```
SELECT
    Headcount.[Snapshot Date],
    Headcount.[ID],
    Assessment.[Assessment Date],
    Assessment.[Code]
FROM Headcount
INNER JOIN Assessment ON Assessment.[ID] = Headcount.[ID]
WHERE Assessment.[Assessment Date] =
(
    SELECT
        MAX(CAST(Assessment.[Assessment Date] AS DATETIME))
    FROM Assessmnet AS Z
    GROUP BY
        Z.ID
    HAVING Z.[ID] = Assessment.[ID]
           AND Assessment.[Assessment Date] <= Headcount.[Snapshot Date]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write `MAX(CAST(Z.[Assessment Date] as datetime))` instead of `MAX(CAST(Assessment.[Assessment Date] as datetime))`. Otherwise, you're aggregating across the wrong table.

The following query might work (untested!):

```
SELECT Headcount.[Snapshot Date]
, Headcount.[ID]
, Assessment.[Assessment Date]
, Assessment.[Code]
FROM Headcount
INNER JOIN Assessment ON Assessment.[ID] = Headcount.[ID]
WHERE Assessment.[Assessment Date] =
                 (SELECT MAX(CAST(Z.[Assessment Date] as datetime))
                  FROM Assessment AS Z
                  WHERE Z.[ID] = Assessment.[ID] 
                    AND Z.[Assessment Date] <= Headcount.[Snapshot Date])
```

You can also rewrite it to use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) to pick the most recent row for each assessment:

```
SELECT [Snapshot Date], [ID], [Assessment Date], [Code]
FROM (SELECT [Snapshot Date], [ID], [Assessment Date], [Code],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [Assessment Date] DESC) rn
      FROM Headcount JOIN Assessment USING ([ID])
      WHERE [Assessment Date] <= [Snapshot Date]) t
WHERE rn = 1
```